# Converting a history command into a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zsh

This is sort of one of those things that I figured a lot of people would use a lot, but I can't seem to find any people who have written about this sort of thing.

I find that a lot of times I do a lot of iteration on a command-line one-liner and when I end up using it a lot, or anticipate wanting to use it in the future, or when it becomes cumbersome to work with in one line, it generally is a good idea to turn the one-liner into a shell script and stick it somewhere reasonable and easily accessible like `~/bin`.

It's obviously too cumbersome to use any sort of roundabout method involving a text editor to get this done, and it's possible to simply do it on the shell, for instance in zsh typing

```
echo "#!/usr/bin/env sh" > ~/bin/command_from_history_number_523.sh && echo !523 >> ~/bin/command_from_history_number_523.sh
```

followed by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to inject the `!523`rd command and somehow shoehorning it into an acceptable string to be saved.

This is particularly cumbersome and has at minimum three problems:

- Does not work in bash as it does not complete the `!523`
- Requires some manual inspection and string escapement
- Requires too much typing such as the script name must be entered twice

So it looks like I need to do some meta shell scripting here.

I think a good solution would function under both bash and zsh, and it should probably work by taking two arguments, an integer for the history command number and a name for the shell script to poop out in a hardcoded directory which contains that one command. Furthermore, under bash, it appears that multi-line commands are treated as separate commands, but I'm willing to assume that we only care about one-liners here and I only use zsh anyway at this point.

The stumbling block here is that i think I'll still be running shell scripts through bash even when using zsh, so it won't likely then be able to parse zsh's history files. I may need to make this into two separate programs then.

**Update**: I agree with @Floris 's comment that direct use of the commands like !! would be helpful though I am not sure how to make this work. Suppose I have the usage be

```
mkscript command_number_24 !24
```

this is inadequate because `mkscript` will be receiving the expanded out contents of the 24th command. if the 24th command contains any file globs or somesuch they will have been expanded already. This is bad, and I basically want the contents of the history file, i.e. the raw command string. I guess this can be worked around by manually implementing those shortcuts in here. Or just screw it and just take an integer argument.

Comment: I disagree with the premise "It is obviously too cumbersome to use ... a text editor".  When a script fragment needs to become reusable, I need to revise it so that it processes arguments, etc.  Often it means improving error handling.  Those are things I do best in a text editor.  I use the 'history edit' mechanism (vi-mode in `bash` launching `vim`) to edit the script once more, saving it to a file in ~/bin and then deleting and saving it from the buffer (so it is not executed once more).  Then I can fix up the script; add the leading comment that identifies what it does, etc.

Comment: Just to make sure your question is clear: you would like a script (let's call it `mkscript`) that is called with `makescript somename !123` that creates a "wrapper" for the command that is number 123 in your history. I would recommend that the `!` can be included just so you can type `!!` for the last command and not have to figure out the history number. You could test whether the second argument is a single integer or a string in order to confirm the syntax used. Is that the kind of thing you have in mind? I have to agree with @JonathanLeffler 's observation, though...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Your point is valid, however it is totally reasonable also for me to do this **and then go in the text editor** with the shell script shebang already created for me, etc. Floris, yes.

Comment: I should have said "It is potentially overkill to require use of a text editor". It is probably *not* "obviously too cumbersome" for all but the laziest of us. I am endlessly diligent in aspiring to become maximally lazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function mkscript() { 
    echo '#!/bin/bash' > ~/bin/$2
    history -p '!'$1 >> ~/bin/$2
}
```

Only tested in Bash.

Update from OP: In zsh I can accomplish this with `fc -l $2 $2`